# How to upload a file from WinXP PC to Ubuntu server?

Tags: windows-xp, ftp

I have tried to login through putty and then use sftp inside a linux environment to transfer a file to server, but not successful. I also do not know how to write local file address/path correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to use SFTP inside a SSH session, you should use SFTP directly, for example using [`psftp`](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), PuTTY’s SFTP client, or [WinSCP](http://winscp.net), an easy-to-use SFTP client with a regular Windows GUI.

SFTP clients establish the required SSH connection automatically. There’s no need for you to do it. Just think of the SFTP client as an alternative SSH client. Only it manages and transfers files instead of displaying a command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I really think you are going to want to use something like winscp or putty's built in SFTP client. Is there a reason that you can't use those.